# ¿Como actualizar el valor de un componente dinámicamente con React?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, jsx

Cada vez que el botón `nextLap` es presionado, cambia la serie, que se ve reflejado en `this.props.serie`,

Los demás elementos se ven modificados como es de esperar, sin embargo el elemento `initialTime` dentro del componente `Timer` no se modifica. Se queda con el primer valor.

Llevo un par de semanas atorado con esto, y ya no se por donde buscarle

También he intentado pasando el `props` directamente pero sigue sin cambiar.

```
export default class SerieDisplay extends Component {
  state = {
    paso: this.props.serie.paso
  };
  render() {
    const { estilo, paso } = this.props.serie;
    const { nextLap, prevLap } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={style}>
        <p>Estilo: {estilo}</p>
        <button onClick={this.props.prevLap}>{`<<`}</button>
        Vuelta {this.props.vuelta}
        de {vueltas}
        <button onClick={this.props.nextLap}>{`>>`}</button>
        <p>Paso {paso}</p>
        <Timer
          initialTime={1000}
          //intialTime={this.props.serie.paso}
          //intialTime={paso}
          direction="backward"
          startImmediately={false}
          timeToUpdate={100}
        >
          {({ start, resume, pause, stop, reset, timerState }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <div>
                <Timer.Seconds /> seconds
                <Timer.Milliseconds /> milliseconds
              </div>
              <br />
              <div>
                <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>
                <button>{`|<`}</button>
                <button onClick={pause}>{`||`}</button>
                <button onClick={start}>{`>`}</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleNext}>{`>|`}</button>
              </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </Timer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tu código tiene errores de sintaxis. Tu elemento `<React.Fragment>` está suelto en el código. Por favor pon un [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: listo, duda ligera, que herramienta usas?

Comment: No sé a que herramienta te refieres. ¿has probado lo descrito en `Change props dynamically and use HOC` de la [documentación](https://volkov97.github.io/react-compound-timer/)?

Comment: he probado de todo, no termino de entender la documentación, creo que es algo sobre pasar props a refs o modificar las refs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede está relacionado a cómo se esta manejando el componente **react-compound-timer**, este componente recibe el parámetro **initialTime** el cual le indica el tiempo de duración.

Cuando presionas el botón **nextLap** el mismo cambia las props de forma correcta pero el componente **react-compound-timer** no valida que hubo un cambio de props por lo cual no reinicia sus estados y sigue trabajando con el **initialTime** inicial.

Te comparto una solución a este problema.

1 - Al componente Timer le agregas una referencia de esta forma:

```
<Timer
  //initialTime={1000}
  ref={(ref) => {this.timer = ref;}}
  initialTime={this.props.serie.paso}
  ...
```

2 - Posteriormente agregas una validación en el **componentDidUpdate** del propio componente **SerieDisplay** quedándote mas menos así:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
  const { serie: { paso: prevPaso } } = prevProps;
  const { serie: { paso: currentPaso } } = this.props;

  if(prevPaso !== currentPaso){
    this.timer.setTime(currentPaso);
  }
}
```

Lo que se está haciendo acá es validando que cuando cambie la **prop** de **serie.paso** entonces se reinicie el **timer** con el nuevo valor.

Espero pueda servirte.
Saludos.

PD: **Ejemplo funcional.**

[image: Imagen de ejemplo funcionando]